# What, if any, hydration states does sodium bicarbonate have?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure

Sodium carbonate has a few hydrates in addition to the anhydrous form. I haven't found any references online that assert any hydrates of sodium bicarbonate though. Do they simply not exist?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge sodium hydrogen carbonate hydrates do not exist.

However, there exists a mixed hydrate of sodium carbonate and sodium hydrogen carbonate with the formula $\ce{Na2CO3 \cdot NaHCO3 \cdot 2H2O}$ (dihydrate of [trisodium hydrogendicarbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_sesquicarbonate), $\ce{Na3H(CO3)2}$) that occurs naturally as the mineral [trona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trona).

The region labeled *trona* in the phase diagram below shows the conditions under which the hydrate can be crystallized from an aqueous solution of $\ce{Na2CO3}$ and $\ce{NaHCO3}$.

[image: Image from US patent US7638109B2]

<sub>The picture is taken from [US patent US7638109B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7638109).</sub>